# Looped function calling not looping correctly! (C++)

Tags: c++

I am doing a homework for my Systems Programming course.
I have to implement a University simulation.
I have a Course abstract class, and child class of it ComputerScienceCourse (and a bunch of other child classes that don't affect what I'm going to ask).
and I have a Student abstract class, and child class of it ComputerScienceStudent (and a bunch of other child classes that don't affect what I'm going to ask).
In the ComputerScienceCourse child class there is a function:

```
void teach(){
 for(i = all students that take this course [stored in a vector of pointers to Student objects, which is a member field of the CSCourse child class, called students]){
  this->students.at(i)->study(*this);
 }
}
```

This function calls study function for all students that have taken this class. The function is a member function of child class CSStudent

```
void study(Course &c){
 if(this->failedclass){
  c.removeStudent(this)
 }
}
```

Now when I check the output, the loop in the teach function does not call the study function for all the students within.
For example, if I have 4 students doing this course, sometimes it would call the study function of only the first three, sometimes it calls the function for the first and the last student... varies.
What could be causing the for loop to not call ALL students study functions?!
Here's the full code for the teach function:

```
    for(unsigned int i=0; i<this->studentMembers.size(); i++){

    this->studentMembers.at(i)->study(*this);

}
```

Comment: Provide compiling code that exhibits the problem

Comment: I suggest you supply the actual code for the `for` loop in `teach()`, since that's the likely source of the problem.

Comment: Post the exact code you are using to iterate through the students.

Comment: done. And there is no compiling code to exhibit this, I just use std::cout to see who actually taken what.
For example: std::cout << "Teaching the course for " << this->studentMembers.at(i)->getId() << std::endl;

Comment: Is `study` a virtual function?  Could an overridden version be getting called?

Comment: study is a pure virtual function in the base class Student.
However it is not virtual in the child class ComputerScienceStudent.
And I think that the compiler knows which function to call, in this case, the CS Student object study function.

Comment: The Homework tag is [deprecated](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated)

Comment: Um, yes, it's virtual in `ComputerScienceStudent`. It just isn't **marked** virtual. But it overrides a virtual function, so it's virtual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be that when a student fails a course, the contents of the vector get modified. Removing things from a vector while you're iterating through its contents is tricky to get right. Seems like a more appropriate data model here would have the instructor remove students who fail, which would also make this problem much more tractable. So teach everyone, and then go through the list again to remove students who failed.

Comment: Wow. I just noticed that I -DO- change the vector whilist im iterating through its contents!
Thank you. will edit and give feedback!